# DropDown list in yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

In my form I have following designing
Template dropdown list
name     Textbox
from     Textbox
subject  textbox
content  textbox

If i m selecting any template from template then remaining fields like name,from,subject,etc can be changed a per selection of template...

please give the solution for this

```
    <div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'profile_id'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'profile_id', CHtml::listData(Email::model()->findAll(), 'email_id', 'name'), array('empty'=>'---Select Template---')); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'profile_id'); ?>
   </div>
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#dropdownlist").change(function(
   var value = this.val();
   switch (value) {
       case 'template1':
           // change fields
       break;
       case 'template2':
           // change fields
       break;
       default:
          alert("ERROR: this template not exist.");
   }
));
```